# Git clone --reference fails with "reference repository as a linked checkout is not supported yet."

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone with `--reference` a local repository, like:

`git clone --reference ./ ./ ../test-clone`

But it's failing with the following error:

`fatal: reference repository './' as a linked checkout is not supported yet.`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to clone from a `git worktree`, and not a fully self-standing repo. A "linked checkout" is git's name for a `worktree`, as mentioned in its manpage, `git-worktree(1)`.

You can only clone with `--reference` from a non-`worktree` repo, like the original of the worktree.

Comment: Despite the worktree, it's abnormal to use `./` as the reference repository and `./` as the remote repository.